# Html wont show font awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Hi I'm trying to get check box icons and a plus symbol to show up on my checkbox tags on my site. I put this css code in the pages main .css file but the icons wont show up. Heres the .css that contains the font awesome info. I've been trying for ages to make it work but nothing seems to help. Does it need a new css file? I put the css in the sites main index.css file. But still breaks the font awesome font code.
Thanks!

```css
.container {
    max-width: 640px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li{
  display: inline;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li label{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    border: 2px solid rgba(139, 139, 139, .3);
    color: #adadad;
    border-radius: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 2px;
    content: "\f067";
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    content: "\f00c";
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    border: 2px solid #1bdbf8;
    background-color: #12bbd4;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: absolute;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label {
  border: 2px solid #e9a1ff;
}
```

Heres the site for the html http://dashcraft.net

Heres where I got it from https://codepen.io/quinlo/pen/ReMRXz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the correct awesome version. Just link that one, then you can run it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works now. :)